# Ansible through WinRM: win_find throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: powershell, ansible, winrm

I'm working on some Ansible playbooks that have to run on Windows Server 2008 with Powershell 3.

As part of one of these playbooks I do a win_find to get a list of files in a directory:

```
- name: filecheck
  win_find:
    paths:  C:\dev\envs
  register: envs
```

When I try to run the playbook, it runs correctly through preliminary operations (eg printing some debug variables) but then errors out when the above operation is executed:

```
"module_stderr": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.\r\nAt line:60 char:9\r\n+     If (-not $obj.GetType)\r\n+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], OutOfMemoryException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException\r\n \r\n\r\n",
```

Now I don't see a scenario where a non-recursive find on a folder with three files would be able to consume 150MB of memory, let alone the 2048 that's been allocated to shells over WinRM.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue or try and find the root cause?

Comment: It turns out I needed this fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2842230/-out-of-memory-error-on-a-computer-that-has-a-customized-maxmemorypershellmb-quota-set-and-has-wmf-3.0-installed